# Regional Economic Accounts from BEA in a single dataset

Tags: usa, economics

The Bureau of Economic Analysis has some basic data on the US state and metropolitan areas:

- http://www.bea.gov/regional/index.htm

It also has bulk downloads and a query system.

Still, I wonder whether anyone put all this data together in a single panel dataset for quick access?

Comment: Anton - can you maybe specify which datasets you are looking for combined? I haven't come across such a dataset but perhaps someone  here (myself included) will share some tips or do it for you if you scope it down a little

Comment: @Skram Thanks! I'd like the basic BEA data (state GDP, population, income, price index) as it's done in PWT for countries.